# "fsolve" doesn't work for system nonlinear equation

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, equation

I have these equations:

```
syms pm pr teta s  
A1 = -2 * b1 * pm + 2 * b2 * pr + b * teta + (1-t) * s + (1-p) * a + c * (b1 - b2);
A2 = 2 * b2 * pm + 2 * b1 * pr + (1-b) * teta + t * s + p * a + c * (b1 - b2);
A3 = b * pm + (1-b) * pr - n * teta - c;
A4 = (1-t) * pm + t * pr - k * s - c;
eqns = [A1,A2,A3,A4];

F=@(pm, pr, teta, s) [A1
                      A2
                      A3
                      A4];
                      
x0 = [10, 10, 10, 10];
fsolve(F, x0)
```

How I can solve them?
(When I use fsolve, it shows this error: FSOLVE requires all values returned by functions to be of data type double)

Comment: The Matlab documentation for fsolve looks like it expects equations to only have the variables that you are solving for in them.  If your equations were made up of nothing but numbers and pm,pr,teta,s then I think it might work. But you have lots of other variables in there. So any solution seems like it is going to be four big symbolic expressions, not four (double) constants. Does that make sense? Can you perhaps find other solvers in Matlab that might deal with symbolic solutions? (quick question, why did you include wolfram-mathematica as a tag in your question)

Comment: @Bill  I define variables, and others are parameters that I have their value, and I import these data from Excel. Actually, I have four equations with four variables. do you have any suggestions to solve them? (I mentioned Wolfram-Mathematica because these equations can solve in this software as well)

Comment: @Bill is correct that Matlab may not like symbolic expressions, but I think the error is indicating that Matlab is expecting `F` to return a one double. It seems you are returning an array of four doubles.

Comment: @RPM So how do I solve it? Which function can solve these equations?

Comment: You can't minimise an array of four doubles. You need to be more explicit about what the minimum is. Are you trying to minimise the smallest of these four values? The largest of these four values? The mean? The median?

Comment: @RPM I'm trying to find out the value of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged Mathematica

```
A1 = -2*b1*pm + 2*b2*pr + b*teta + (1 - t)*s + (1 - p)*a + c*(b1 - b2);
A2 = 2*b2*pm + 2*b1*pr + (1 - b)*teta + t*s + p*a + c*(b1 - b2);
A3 = b*pm + (1 - b)*pr - n*teta - c;
A4 = (1 - t)*pm + t*pr - k*s - c;

FullSimplify[Solve[{A1 == 10, A2 == 10, A3 == 10, A4 == 10}, {pm, pr, teta, s}]]
```

> pm -> ((k ((-1 + b)^2 + 2 b1 n) + n t^2) (b (10 + c) k +
> n (10 + c + 10 k - a k - b1 c k + b2 c k +
> a k p - (10 + c) t)) + ((-1 + b) (10 + c) k +
> k n (-10 + b1 c - b2 c + a p) - (10 + c) n t) (b k - b^2 k +
> n (2 b2 k + t - t^2)))/(k n (1 - 2 b1 k + b^2 (1 + 4 b2 k) +
> 2 (b1 - 2 (b1^2 + b2^2) k) n - 2 t -
> 4 (b1 + b2) n t + (1 + 4 b2 n) t^2 +
> 2 b (-1 + 2 b1 k - 2 b2 k + t)))

> pr -> (c +
> b^2 (10 + c - (-20 + a + 2 b1 c - 2 b2 c) k) + 2 b1^2 c k n -
> b2 (20 + c - 2 (-10 + a) k + 2 b2 c k) n - a (1 + 2 b2 k) n p -
> 2 b1 k (10 + c + n (10 - a p)) + 10 (1 + n - 2 t) -
> c (2 + b2 n) t +
> n (-30 + a + 20 b2 + a p) t + (10 + c - (-20 + a) n +
> 2 b2 c n) t^2 - b1 n (c + 20 t + c t (-1 + 2 t)) +
> b (k (-10 + a + 20 b1 - 20 b2 - a p) + 20 (-1 + t) +
> c (-2 + 3 b1 k - 3 b2 k + 2 t)))/(1 - 2 b1 k +
> b^2 (1 + 4 b2 k) + 2 (b1 - 2 (b1^2 + b2^2) k) n - 2 t -
> 4 (b1 + b2) n t + (1 + 4 b2 n) t^2 +
> 2 b (-1 + 2 b1 k - 2 b2 k + t))

> teta -> (10 - 20 b2 - b2 c -
> 20 b2 k + 2 a b2 k + 40 b2^2 k + 2 b2^2 c k +
> 2 b1^2 (20 + 3 c) k - a p -
> 2 a b2 k p + (-30 + 3 b2 (20 + c) + a (1 + p)) t - (-20 + a +
> 2 b2 (20 + c)) t^2 +
> b (-10 - 4 b1^2 c k + a p +
> b1 (20 + 40 k - 2 a k + c (3 + 4 b2 k - 2 t)) + 20 t - a t +
> b2 (20 + c - 2 a k + 4 a k p - 2 (20 + c) t)) +
> b1 (2 k (-10 + a p) + 20 (-1 + t) + c (-3 + (5 - 2 t) t)))/(1 -
> 2 b1 k + b^2 (1 + 4 b2 k) + 2 (b1 - 2 (b1^2 + b2^2) k) n - 2 t -
> 4 (b1 + b2) n t + (1 + 4 b2 n) t^2 +
> 2 b (-1 + 2 b1 k - 2 b2 k + t))

> s -> (20 b1 + b1 c - b2 c -
> 2 b^2 (-10 + b1 c + b2 (20 + c)) + 20 b1 n + 40 b1^2 n -
> 20 b2 n + 40 b2^2 n + 2 b1^2 c n + 4 b1 b2 c n +
> 2 b2^2 c n - (b1 - b2) (20 + c) t +
> 4 b1 (-10 + b1 c - b2 c) n t - 10 (-1 + 2 b2 + t) +
> a (-1 - b^2 - 2 b1 n + p + 2 (b1 + b2) n p + t - p t +
> 2 n (b1 + b2 - 2 b2 p) t - b (-2 + p + t)) +
> b (-(-10 + b2 (20 + c)) (-3 + 2 t) + b1 (-20 + c - 2 c t)))/(1 -
> 2 b1 k + b^2 (1 + 4 b2 k) + 2 (b1 - 2 (b1^2 + b2^2) k) n - 2 t -
> 4 (b1 + b2) n t + (1 + 4 b2 n) t^2 +
> 2 b (-1 + 2 b1 k - 2 b2 k + t))